# Regex to match vowels in order as they appear once

Tags: regex, perl

I trying to figure out a correct regex to match vowels in a word as they appear.
There may be any number of consonants in the word; however, there should be no other vowels other than the 5 listed above.  For example, the word “sacrilegious” should not match because, although it contains the five vowels in alphabetical order, there is an extra ‘i’ vowel located between the ‘a’ and the ‘e’.  Hyphenated words are not allowed.  In fact, your regular expression should not match any ‘word’ that contains any character other than the upper and lower case letters.

Here are some words that it should match

```
abstemious
facetious
arsenious
acheilous
anemious
caesious
```

This is what I have come up with so far, but when I run the program it doesn't seem to be doing what it should do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


my $test =  "abstemious";

if( $test =~ /a[^eiou]*e[^aiou]*i[^aeou]*o[^aeiu]u/ )
{

    print "yes";

}
```

Comment: Do you want to match `intravenous`?

Comment: @Tim intravenous should not match since the vowels do not appear once in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a small typo there, try this:

```
/a[^eiou]*e[^aiou]*i[^aeou]*o[^aeio]*u/
```

Comment: Of course this only works if those vowels appear in the order `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`. They happen to do so in all the test cases.

Comment: This also matches words like "unabstemious", hyphenated words, and phrases such as "an evil out".

Answer (score 2):

You're not too far off. Try this regex:

```
/\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*a[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*e[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*i[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*o[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*u[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\b/i
```

`[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*` matches any number of consonants, then it's just slotting in the vowels and the word boundary markers (`\b`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this regexp:

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z]+)[^aA]*?[aA][^aeAE]*?[eE][^aeiAEI]*?[iI][^aeioAEIO]*?[oO][^aeiouAEIOU]*?[uU][^aeiouAEIOU]*?\b
```

Comment: This isn't right since it matches sacrilegious.

Comment: There you go. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is it okay for a word to contain duplicate vowels, as long as they're in the correct order?  For example, would `faaceetiioouus` (if there were such a word) be acceptable?  I ask because your current regex does indeed match it.

If you want to match only words that contain exactly one of each vowel, try this:

```
/^
 (?=[a-z0-9]+$)
 [^aeiou]*a
 [^aeiou]*e
 [^aeiou]*i
 [^aeiou]*o
 [^aeiou]*u
 [^aeiou]*
 $
/ix
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, if you don't mind making a temporary copy of the string:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $test = $_;
    my $cp   = $test; # leave original string intact
    $cp =~ tr/aeiou//cd;
    print "$test\n" if $cp eq 'aeiou';
}

=for output

abstemious
facetious
arsenious
acheilous
anemious
caesious

=cut

__DATA__
abstemious
facetious
arsenious
acheilous
anemious
caesious
unabstemious
sacrilegious
intravenous
faaceetiioouus
```