# Postgresql: how to copy multiple columns from one table to another?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to copy some columns from a table called `temporarytable` to another one called `scalingData` using `psycopg2` in `python`.

`scalingData` is a pandas dataframe. The dataframe contains data from cities such as: `nameOfCities`, `population`, etc.

```
scalingData = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv')  ## 'myFile.csv' is the datasource
```

each column of the dataframe has a different kind of data, such as `'int64'`, `'float64'` or `'O'`.

Here a screen shot from `Jupyter`

[image]

```
import psycopg2 as ps
## Populate table scalingData
tmp = scalingData.dtypes
con = None
con = ps.connect(dbname = 'mydb', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='mypd')
con.autocommit = True
cur = con.cursor()
for i in range(0,5):
    j = header[i]
    stat = """  ALTER TABLE "scalingData" ADD COLUMN "%s" """%j
    if tmp[i] == 'int64':
        stat = stat+'bigint'
    if tmp[i] == 'float64':
        stat = stat+'double precision'
    if tmp[i] == 'O':
        stat = stat+'text'
    ### Add Column
    cur.execute(stat)
    stat1 = """INSERT INTO "scalingData" ("%s") SELECT "%s" FROM temporarytable"""%(j,j)
    ### Copy Column
    cur.execute(stat1)
cur.close()    
con.close()
```

My problem is that if I look at `scalingData` only the first column is copied while the others are empty.

Here a screenshot of the table from `pgAdmin` afer the query:

Also if I copy for instance the second column as first column it works, but then it fails with the others as well.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you expect the results to be? It would be nice to see a display of the input (tables/data) and the expected output (tables/data)

Comment: This code isn't runnable by itself. What is `scalingData.dtypes`? What are `header` and `tmp`? Can you show the contents of `stat` before calling `cur.execute`? And similarly for `stat1`?

Comment: @AK47 I would like to populate a the table I created on `postgres`. My problem is that I can only populate the first column. Then if I try to populate the second column it is empty

Comment: @emax does the `scalingData` table exist prior to this? Is there any reason you don't want to create a table from scratch with the columns automatically defined as per your dataframe and then just insert the rows?

Comment: And is just the first 5 columns an example or did you want the whole 68 in your table?

Comment: Or am I reading this wrong and the `scalingData` dataframe is somewhat a red herring here... You want to use it only copy data from an existing table `temporarytable` where the column names are identical (but may/may not exist in the `scalingData` table? You're not just after being able to load the dataframe straight into the `scalingData` table?

Comment: Screenshot of `pgAdmin` table doesn't seem to be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you add 1 field to your new table, than insert data only with that field set up, and you do it 5 times. So you should actually see 5 copies of your original table with only 1 field set up.

You need to first set up the structure for your `scalingData` table, then insert all the records with all fields.

Here is the code (not a Python developer):

```
import psycopg2 as ps
## Populate table scalingData
tmp = scalingData.dtypes
con = None
con = ps.connect(dbname = 'mydb', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='mypd')
con.autocommit = True
cur = con.cursor()
for i in range(0,5):
    j = header[i]
    stat = """  ALTER TABLE "scalingData" ADD COLUMN "%s" """%j
    if tmp[i] == 'int64':
        stat = stat+'bigint'
    if tmp[i] == 'float64':
        stat = stat+'double precision'
    if tmp[i] == 'O':
        stat = stat+'text'
    ### Add Column
    cur.execute(stat)

fieldsStr = '"' + '", "'.join([header]) + '"' ### will return "header1", "header2", ... , "header5"
stat1 = """INSERT INTO "scalingData" (%s) SELECT %s FROM temporarytable"""%(fieldsStr,fieldsStr)
### Copy Table
cur.execute(stat1)

cur.close()    
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python, but just a guess as to where the issue might be coming from:

```
"""INSERT INTO "scalingData" ("%s") SELECT "%s" FROM temporarytable"""
```

... will transform the `"%s"` bit into `"foo, bar, baz"` rather than `"foo", "bar", "baz"`.

Put another way you should remove the unneeded double quotes in your statement and escape the individual column names instead.

Double quotes are used in PG to quote identifiers. You can literally have an table or column called `"foo, bar, baz"` and PG will work just fine when you do - provided it's always in-between double quotes when you use it in a statement.

Comment: May I request you to [vote to undelete nad reopen this old question please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6067276/548225)